# Windows Defender stops automatically after a few hours. (Windows server 2016)

Tags: windows-server-2016

Good morning.

This has been happening to me for a long time. The Windows Defender service stops after a few hours of running.

In the event viewer I only see this error:

"The Windows Defender Service service terminated unexpectedly. This has happened 2 times."

Event ID: 7034

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to repair Windows Defender with DISM and SFC.

(1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.

(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup

(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth

(4) SFC /SCANNOW

(5) You should restart the Server at this point. Pick an appropriate time and restart when all the above is complete and test Windows Defender.

Comment: @Jonh It is not feasible to implement the above on a domain controller in production.
Greetings.

Comment: The steps are simple and generally effective.  I noted the need to pick an appropriate time to restart. Windows Defender is built-in and I do not know another way to repair Defender.